# Calculate Frequency Count for each statement in the following C code

Tags: c, algorithm

How do I calculate the frequency count of each statement (i.e. the number of time each statement gets read/executed) in the following C code.
The frequency count of each statement must be written in terms of 'n'.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  
     for(j=1;j<=i;j++)  
          for(k=1;k<=j;k++)
                x=x+1;
```

Comment: Huh, school assignment?

Comment: No. Was trying to solve some random tricky question from the net on C programming and found this. I already know the answer for the first two statements (if I am correct). n+1 and n(n+1)/2 respectively. @HiI'mFrogatto

Comment: Tip: `1+2+3+.....+N = (N+1)*N/2`

Comment: Are you intrested in complexity or numbers of times a particular instruction was executed actually.

Comment: The number of times a particular statement was executed. @PriyanshGoel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this way, at maximum ,

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  // Executes n times
     for(j=1;j<=i;j++)  // Executes i times for every i -> (1 + 2 + 3 + 4....n)
          for(k=1;k<=j;k++) // Executes j times for every i,j ---> (1+(1+2)+(1+2+3).....(1+2+3...n)) 
                x=x+1; // Executes every time for every i,j,k ---> (1+(1+2)+.....(1+2+3...n)

 So, you can figure out from this that :
```

`n + n*(n+1)/2 + (n+(n-1)2+(n-2)3.....(1)n)*2 ...` 
= `n + n(n+1)/2+ ((n)(n+1)(n+2)/6)*2`   .. This is your answer.

Comment: I guess you have written the total number of times all the statements will execute. Right?

Comment: Yes. Thats what you wanted, Right?

Comment: @DeepakTalan:     I have written it both ways. I have written the number of times each instruction will execute and also total number of times all instructions will execute in  the complete code.

Comment: Oh, I see. @PriyanshGoel

Answer (score 1):

- The first for loop executes n times.
- The second for loop executes: 1 + 2 + 3 +..... +n = n(n+1)/2
- The third for loop executes: ∑ j(j+1)/2 for j = 1 to n, i.e. 1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + .. + n(n+1)/2. This is called the triangular sequence and the sum is n(n+1)(n+2)/6.

Comment: I guess that's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't this be the right answer than compared to what is currently marked as right answer ? I have provided you the actual calculated sum for all 3 statements in terms of n while the other answer hasn't.

Comment: Omg. This can't be happening. I know you all are craving for reputation points, but don't start acting unprofessional. First he comes up to me explaining why his answer is correct, now you. I marked your answer as correct initially but then he explained how he had written the same thing so I marked his, since he answered before you did. And now I you are telling me that your's is better and should be marked right.

Comment: And I would also like to know why people are downvoting my question. I couldn't find something like this on Stack Overflow, neither am I doing it for some kind of home assignment, then why?

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at just

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
         expression;
```

It will go like:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  
    // i=1, 2, ..., n Total = n
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
         expression;
        // i=1 -> j=1             Total = 1
        // i=2 -> j=1, 2          Total = 2
        // ...
        // i=n -> j=1, 2, ..., n  Total = n
```

So the `expression` is executed 1+2+...+n times which is `(n+1)*n/2`

Now you can calculate the frequency of the individual expressions.

```
i=1;  // 1
i<=n; // n+1
i++;  // n
j=1;  // n
j<i;  // ((n+2)*(n+1)/2) - 1   (2+3+...+(n+1))
j++;  // (n+1)*n/2
```

Using the same method you can add the `for(k=1;k<=j;k++)` and recalculate the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

```
// here for loop code statement will excute for n times
// but when condition is false then also loop run to check
// for condition so hence for loop runs for (n+1) times.


for(i=1;i<=n;i++)         // --------> (n + 1) 

    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)     // --------> (n * (n + 1))

        for(k=1;k<=j;k++) // --------> (n * n * (n + 1)) 

            x=x+1;        // --------> (n * n * n)

// total Frequency Count is :  
//(n + 1) + (n * (n + 1)) + (n * n * (n + 1)) + (n * n * n)
```